# Using __str__() method in Django on Python 2

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am Learning Django using the [Django project tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api). 
Since I use python 2.7 I am unable to implement the following in python 2.7:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
# ...
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
# ...
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: answer is already in the comments!

Comment: Accepted answer should be that one from @alfetopito, because that  technique is the best match for Django’s porting philosophy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To keep the code compatible between py2 and py3, a better way is to use the decorator `python_2_unicode_compatible`.
This way you can keep the **str** method:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
# ...
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.question_text

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
# ...
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.choice_text
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods

> Django provides a simple way to define **str**() and  **unicode**() methods that work on Python 2 and 3: you must define a **str**() method returning text and to apply the python_2_unicode_compatible() decorator.
>
> ...
>
> This technique is the best match for Django’s porting philosophy.

Comment: I just passed along this post, and I think will be nice to note that you can make a [recursion depth exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669376/cannot-make-custom-str-calling-parents-str-in-django/42670768) if you try to use a child `__str__` that calls its parent's `__str__` with that decorator. Something to be aware of. Sorry for the necro.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, you just replace `__str__` with `__unicode__`, as the comment states:

```
class Question(models.Model):
# ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
# ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Further down that section you'll find a bit of explanation:

> ### `__str__` or `__unicode__?`
>
> On Python 3, it’s easy, just use `__str__()`.
>
> **On Python 2, you should define `__unicode__()` methods returning unicode values instead.** Django models have a default `__str__()` method that calls `__unicode__()` and converts the result to a UTF-8 bytestring. This means that `unicode(p)` will return a Unicode string, and `str(p)` will return a bytestring, with characters encoded as UTF-8. Python does the opposite: object has a `__unicode__` method that calls `__str__` and interprets the result as an ASCII bytestring. This difference can create confusion.

The `question_text` and `choice_text` attributes return Unicode values already.