# Cannot make custom __str__ calling parent's __str__ in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

Although I know how to make it, and have searched examples for comparing my code, I cannot get why I cannot call a model that has its `__str__` calling inside its parent's `__str__`. I get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__`
, which should not be happening.

Here is my code below. No collateral work that could be affecting it:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class A(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.attr

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class B(A):
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (super(B, self).__str__(), self.attr_two)
```

Comment: This code would work. You'll need to show the real code and the traceback (or as much of it until it starts repeating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to know what was happening. It was because of  the decorator **python_2_unicode_compatible** (`from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible`). Here's the traceback where problem starts:

```
/my/path/to/django/utils/six in <lambda>(self)
    840                              klass.__name__)
    841         klass.__unicode__ = klass.__str__
--> 842         klass.__str__ = lambda self: self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
    843     return klass
    844
```

So, the decorator assigns `__str__` to `__unicode__`, then assigns to `__str__` a lambda which calls `__unicode__` (circular dependency). And that's how you go to *"Infinity! And beyond!"* in recursion terms. Deleting the decorator and changing the class methods to `__unicode__` solves the problem.

**EDIT**

An alternative to keep the decorator would be adding a custom method in the parent:

```
def str(self):
    return "foo"

def __str__(self):
    return self.str()
```

Then in the child you just do `self.str()` also.

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` is on per object, not per class. So, you would do:

```
class B(A):

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.attr, self.attr_two)
```